# Calculate area if points aren't sorted

Tags: c++, math

Okay, here's my code for calculating area of quadrilateral; this works fine:

```
float Pk(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2,float x3,float y3,float x4,float y4)
{
    return abs(((x1*y2)-(x2*y1))+((x2*y3)-(x3*y2))+((x3*y4)-(x4*y3))+((x4*y1)-(x1*y4)))/2;
}
```

But the problem is that points were not given in any order. For example, for this quadrilateral [image]

points were given like:

- 9 7
- 3 5
- 7 3
- 2 10

And I can't calculate the area like this(Area of ABCD needs to be found). Do you have any idea how to do this, without actually trying every possible combination, cuz my program is a little bit more complex and it would take a lot of time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a random guess: compute average of x & y coordinates, then compute the angle between the average x & y coordinate, and each of the original points. Sort the points by the angle.

Comment: This isn't mathematically possible. If I give points (0,0), (5, 0), (1,1), (0,4), then there are three shapes with those points, and each has a different area.  (The problem is triggered by concave hulls)

Comment: You want to calculate area of which shape? Do you want to calculate the area of convex hull of given points?

Comment: Are you asking just for a quadrilateral, or could the polygon be larger? If larger, first use a [convex hull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) to order the points, then find the area. If the convex hull does not include all four (or however many) vertices, decide what to do--you could just ignore the interior points, or raise an error. If you are doing only quadrilaterals, you could do the equivalent with simpler code.

Comment: @Luka,Rory: Four arbitrary points can't always be forced into a convex hull.

Comment: Am I wrong to suggest vector math???

Comment: Four out-of-order points do not define a unique quadrilateral. Which means that there is no specific quadrilateral and no specific area. If you are supposed to find the "original" quadrilateral, then without extra knowledge the problem is **unsolvable** in general case. End of story.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to sort your points in counter-clockwise order before you call your area function.

To do that, start by finding the center of the bounding box of all your points. Then find the angle between each point and the center point. Sort your list of points based on the angle.

With your sorted list of points, call the area function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate area of convex hull of given points, then simple: Calculate convex hull. Then you will have sorted points of the hull. Then just use your algorithm to calculate area.
There are plenty of algorithms for convex hull calculation. Take a look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: You can get the convex hull of a quadrilateral (the simplest non-trivial case) more easily an efficiently than by using the standard sort-clockwise algorithm.